# How will I convert this ASIFormDataRequest into AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

This is the code Im using for ASIHTTPRequest I want to convert this to AFNetworking

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
                ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
                [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
                [request addPostValue:self.theNewJob.jobID forKey:@"form[job_id]"];
                [request addPostValue:thisJTF.typeFieldID forKey:@"form[jtf_id]"];
                [request setFile:fullPath forKey:@"form[userfile]"];
                [request startSynchronous];
                NSError *error = [request error];
                if (!error) {
                    NSString *response = [request responseString];
                    if ([response isEqualToString:@"SUCCESS"]) {
                        // debugger
                        NSLog(@"signature file uploaded");
                    } else {
                        // debugger
                        NSLog(@"signature file upload Fail: %@ response: %@", error, response);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace all methods manually. I looked for it and I think below link is good to start: http://door3.com/insights/ios-programming-converting-asihttprequest-afnetworking

Comment: thanks man,I already tried that and I'm a bit confused and having errors. haven't used AFNetworking before. The problem I'm having here in ASIHTTPRequest is that I getting an HTML response which is I should get only SUCCESS or FAIL response. If someone can tell me the problem without changing the ASIHTTP would be great

Comment: Whats the response you are getting? Also whats the main motive? To make it work with ASI or to convert into AF?

Comment: That code I'm using is working from the past, I just dont know why the response is getting HTML right now, the response should be SUCCESS or FAIL only. the reason why I want to try AFNetworking is because Im getting HTML response.

Comment: But it may be due to server changes and moving to AF will also not help. Are you using your own server or third party? Can you please post the response you are getting?

Comment: we already checked and deleted the HTML response in the server but still it is getting the HTML response, Yes I'm not sure if it will work if I changed it to AFNetworking.

Comment: I can't paste all the response due character limit

Comment: Does response string has SUCCESS or Fail string? If so the easiest and quickest option would be look for those strings and decide if its Success or fail. Can use below code in this case:   
            NSString * responseStr = [request responseString];
            NSString * successStr = @"SUCCESS";
            NSRange range = [responseStr rangeOfString:successStr];
            if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
                NSLog(@"Success");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Fail");
            }

Comment: No it doesnt have any SUCCESS or FAIL, if we try to check the url we are using in the browser it gives FAIL text. so I think the server is working well. I just can't figure out why the response is giving HTML

Comment: On browser also may be its giving same html? Did you see source of web page? I am almost sure something is wrong at server side. I can help more if you can tell server url.

Comment: its not giving html in the browser. Thanks

Comment: can we talk in skype? what's your skype? I'll add u up

Comment: page source only has FAIL text

Comment: I am not sure if I can post skype id here. May be u can post and I will add u...or email me. You can see my email id in my profile.